# Sparkly run locally testing speed

Tags: r, sparklyr

I was trying an example from sparkly documentation and it seems to go slower than without sparkly.

The following code took over 2 seconds with sparkly, and 0.14 seconds without sparkly:

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
flights_tbl <- copy_to(sc, nycflights13::flights, "flights")

# the following takes 2.3 seconds:
tic()
delay <- flights_tbl %>%
  group_by(tailnum) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), dist = mean(distance), delay = mean(arr_delay)) %>%
  filter(count > 20, dist < 2000, !is.na(delay)) %>%
  collect
toc() 

# takes 2 seconds if cached:
tbl_cache(sc, "flights")
tic()
delay <- flights_tbl %>%
  group_by(tailnum) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), dist = mean(distance), delay = mean(arr_delay)) %>%
  filter(count > 20, dist < 2000, !is.na(delay)) %>%
  collect
toc() 

# 0.14 seconds without sparkly
tic()
delay <- nycflights13::flights %>%
  group_by(tailnum) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), dist = mean(distance), delay = mean(arr_delay)) %>%
  filter(count > 20, dist < 2000, !is.na(delay)) %>%
  collect
toc() # 0.14
```

sc is showing 12 cores:

```
$config$spark.sql.shuffle.partitions.local
[1] 12
```

Why does this code go slower with sparkly? When I use functions like parLapply, I get a huge speedup. Why is sparkly slowing things down?

Comment: This is due to the overhead of starting a Spark worker, passing data to it,and collect it back. If the overhead is longer than processing the task itself, you only measure the overhead.

Comment: So, you're saying this task really is being run in parallel? Because there is over 300,000 rows so I had thought that would be enough to see a speed boost. Also, why then when the table is cached in memory does the overhead not go away?

Comment: If you are able to run the task in 0.14s without sparkly, this isn't a big data task and you can't expect any gain. To be sure the task is run in parallel, you could have a look at cores activity in task manager after replicating the dataset at least 100 times so that execution takes enough time compared to overhead (make sure you have enough memory)